# Classifier for lipstick colors

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning

I need to classify lips by lipstick they use(basically by color). Currently I have 26 classes but in general it might be above 200.
I already tried to do something convnets and multilayer perceptron. Unfortunately both of them didn't help very much.

1. CNN returned .45 accuracy on test with 3 channels image.
2. With MPL I've got up to .06 accuracy. For this neural net I converted image matrix to vector.

What else would you recommend? And which kind of data preprocessing might be useful here? Currently one of the biggest problem I think on is how to classify very similar lipstick colors. On a real life fotos they look very similar.

Comment: Can you share a few images and desired response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neural Networks are not the magical things. It wouldn't be able to find something that doesn't presented on the image. Since color is the only feature then due to different lighting environments the same color can look differently and there is nothing that you can do about it. The right thing to do is to check whether all mistakes produced by the network are meaningful. In case if even person cannot identify the difference between classes then it's the best than you can have.

Also I don't think that Neural Networks for this problem is the best way to start. I think that it's much easier to try to extract some features from the image. For instance, you can convert each image from RGB to HUE and extract histogram per each channel. Than use this features (per each sample concatenate 3 histograms in one vector) to train some simple classifier like logistic regression or SVM. Histograms are much easier to explore and to understand. In addition, it can be useful to apply some algorithm that crop lips from the image and then extract features.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I understand that nets are not magic think. I also tried apply SVM on raw RGB images and as I expected id didn't help but idea with HUE looks good.

Comment: Pixels in the raw images aren't good prediction features. Each pixel doesn't encode valuable information about the image. I would suggest trying to use some classic computer vision methods for feature extraction from images and use them as an image representation for classifier.